# Fast calculation of commute distances on large graphs (i.e. fast computation of the pseudo-inverse of a large Laplacian / Kirchhoff matrix)

Tags: graphs-and-networks, matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm

I have a large, locally connected and undirected graph $G$ with $\approx 10^4$ vertices and $\approx 10^5$ to $\approx 10^6$ edges.  Moreover I can bound the maximum vertex degree as $Q_{max}$.  I would like to obtain all pairwise commute times between vertices in two sets $(v_{(a,1)}, ..., v_{(a,M)}) \in V_a$ and $(v_{(b,1)}, ..., v_{(b,N)}) \in V_b$ where $N >> M$, and do this without simulation of the underlying Markov process.  To do this I need to compute the Laplacian matrix of $G$ (which is apparently computed using KirchhoffMatrix[G] in Mathematica, and takes about $\approx 50$ milliseconds on an X5690 3.47 GHz Intel Xeon processor), and then to compute its pseudoinverse, which I believe is an $O(n^3)$ operation.

My question is - does Mathematica have a nice way of computing the pseudoinverse for a large Laplacian matrix, allowing me to efficiently extract commute times between pairs of vertices?  How large can $G$ be?

---

Update - Following from Szabolcs comments, can anyone confirm that the time complexity of PseudoInverse[] is $O(n^3)$?

Comment: This is bound to be slow because while your starting matrix is sparse, the inverse is going to be dense.  You can calculate the pseudoinverse using `PseudoInverse`.

Comment: The same as *what* exactly?  It sounds like you are not sure what pseudoinverse means in the context of your problem.  This would be a math question, not a Mathematica one.  Once you know precisely what you want to calculate, we can look at how to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: @Szabolcs You wrote that I should use SingularValueDecomposition[] instead of PseudoInverse[] originally.  I was just curious why you recommended that.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  When I saw your message it was already corrected.  If Mathematica didn't have PseudoInverse built in, you could implement it using SingularValueDecomposition.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry about that - my browser isn't updating quickly because PseudoInverse is apparently automatically running on all the available cores and slowing everything down.  Right, your comments all make sense now, thanks!

Comment: Experiment with small matrices first.  Observe how it's getting slower and slower (is it really O(n^3)?)  Then you can estimate an upper bound on the manageable matrix size.  Don't forget that the memory requirements also increase as O(n^2) and may be the real limit to your problem.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's good advice - working on it.

Comment: The algorithm for computing the SVD (and thus the Moore-Penrose inverse as well) indeed takes $O(n^3)$ effort in general. For your matrix, it's quite likely, unless you can somehow prove that the pseudoinverse is also supposed to be sparse.